# createFromPdu((byte[]) smsobject[i] ) Cannot be cast to byte[] in BroadCastReceiver

Tags: java, android

My objective is need to get SMS detail from BroadcastReceiver, After getting SMS I storing those info in Object and later am unable to cast that into byte to store it in string variable...
Here is my code, I am new to both java and android plz help me on this

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String Orgi_Phonenumber = "";
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.i("MyMessage", "start reading message information");
        Object[] smsobject = new Object[] { (Object) bundle.get("pdus") };
        for (int i = 0; i < smsobject.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage CurrentMessage = SmsMessage
                    .createFromPdu((byte[]) smsobject[i]);
            Orgi_Phonenumber += CurrentMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        }

    }
}
```

Below line is creating the problem

```
SmsMessage CurrentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsobject[i]);
```

error is  **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.receivesms.IncomingSms: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to byte[]**

And plz explain me what is the reason cause for the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Object[] smsobject = (Object[]} bundle.get("pdus");
```